# In Composer why do some dependencies 'Load' from cache and some 'clone' from cache

Tags: composer-php

I'm trying to optimise my `composer install` process on a project. I've installed Prestissimo, moved all my dev dependencies into 'require-dev' and also set 'preferred-install' to 'dist' in my `composer.json` file. All of this has cut down the install from ~4 minutes to ~2 minutes.

My dependencies include some of my own private repos which are on Gitlab, and when I watch the composer install process my repos say 'Cloning from cache' and take a few seconds each to process whereas all of the other dependencies say 'Loading from cache' and process pretty much instantly.

Here's the composer.json

```
{
    "name": "my-project",
    "description": "My Project",
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "require": {
        "toruinteractive/ti-cms": "0.13.1"
    },
    "require-dev" : {
        "yiisoft/yii2-debug": "^2.0@dev"
    },
    "config": {
        "fxp-asset": {
          "installer-paths": {
            "npm-asset-library": "vendor/npm",
            "bower-asset-library": "vendor/bower"
          }
        },
        "process-timeout": 1800,
        "preferred-install" : "dist"
    },
    "extra": {
        "require-bower" : {
            "angular-elastic" : "2.5.*",
            "angular-trix" : "1.0.2",
            "aos":"2.1.1",
            "handlebars" : "4.0.*",
            "bootstrap-toggle" : "^2.2.2",
            "image-map-resizer" : "1.0.*"
        }
    },
    "repositories": [
        { "type": "git", "url" : "git@gitlab.com:ti-cms/ti-banner.git" },
        { "type": "git", "url" : "git@gitlab.com:ti-cms/ti-blog.git" },
        { "type": "git", "url" : "git@gitlab.com:ti-cms/ti-suggest.git" },
        { "type": "git", "url":  "git@gitlab.com:ti-cms/ti-cms.git" },
        { "type": "git", "url":  "git@gitlab.com:ti-cms/ti-dashboard.git" },
        { "type": "git", "url":  "git@gitlab.com:ti-cms/ti-file.git" },
        { "type": "git", "url":  "git@gitlab.com:ti-cms/ti-image.git" },
        { "type": "git", "url":  "git@gitlab.com:ti-cms/ti-export-import.git" },
        { "type": "git", "url":  "git@gitlab.com:ti-cms/ti-login.git" },
        { "type": "git", "url":  "git@gitlab.com:ti-cms/ti-navbar.git" },
        { "type": "git", "url":  "git@gitlab.com:ti-cms/ti-page.git" },
        { "type": "git", "url":  "git@gitlab.com:ti-cms/ti-search.git" },
        { "type": "git", "url":  "git@gitlab.com:ti-cms/ti-slides.git" },
        { "type": "git", "url":  "git@gitlab.com:ti-cms/ti-superadmin.git" },
        { "type": "git", "url":  "git@gitlab.com:ti-cms/ti-translator.git" },
        { "type": "git", "url":  "git@gitlab.com:ti-cms/ti-tree.git" }
    ]
}
```

and here's the `composer install` output...

```
ghost$ composer install
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Package operations: 45 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals
  - Installing yiisoft/yii2-composer (2.0.5): Loading from cache
  - Installing bower-asset/jquery (3.2.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing bower-asset/bootstrap (v3.3.7): Loading from cache
  - Installing bower-asset/inputmask (3.3.10): Loading from cache
  - Installing bower-asset/punycode (v1.3.2): Loading from cache
  - Installing bower-asset/yii2-pjax (2.0.7.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing cebe/markdown (1.1.2): Loading from cache
  - Installing ezyang/htmlpurifier (v4.9.3): Loading from cache
  - Installing psr/log (1.0.2): Loading from cache
  - Installing monolog/monolog (1.23.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing paragonie/random_compat (v2.0.11): Loading from cache
  - Installing phenx/php-font-lib (0.4): Loading from cache
  - Installing phenx/php-svg-lib (0.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing phpoffice/phpexcel (1.8.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing yiisoft/yii2 (2.0.13.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing bower-asset/jquery-ui (1.11.4): Loading from cache
  - Installing yiisoft/yii2-jui (2.0.6): Loading from cache
  - Installing yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap (2.0.7): Loading from cache
  - Installing yiisoft/yii2-httpclient (2.0.5): Loading from cache
  - Installing yiisoft/yii2-authclient (2.1.4): Loading from cache
  - Installing toruinteractive/ti-tree (0.13.1): Cloning 867ff3625c from cache
  - Installing toruinteractive/ti-translator (0.13.1): Cloning eec41060e4 from cache
  - Installing toruinteractive/ti-superadmin (0.13.1): Cloning a783cd0bb9 from cache
  - Installing toruinteractive/ti-suggest (0.13.1): Cloning b52895d1ab from cache
  - Installing toruinteractive/ti-slides (0.13.1): Cloning e0a5f9738f from cache
  - Installing toruinteractive/ti-search (0.13.1): Cloning a2e1f8ac89 from cache
  - Installing toruinteractive/ti-page (0.13.1): Cloning 9b3653a648 from cache
  - Installing toruinteractive/ti-navbar (0.13.1): Cloning 711fe81e0a from cache
  - Installing toruinteractive/ti-login (0.13.1): Cloning e7f64c010b from cache
  - Installing imagine/imagine (v0.6.3): Loading from cache
  - Installing flowjs/flow-php-server (v1.0.3): Loading from cache
  - Installing toruinteractive/ti-image (0.13.1): Cloning 5089e00de0 from cache
  - Installing toruinteractive/ti-file (0.13.1): Cloning 68ec65c025 from cache
  - Installing arogachev/yii2-excel (0.1.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing toruinteractive/ti-export-import (0.13.1): Cloning cd8309c01d from cache
  - Installing toruinteractive/ti-dashboard (0.13.1): Cloning ccb9d159e4 from cache
  - Installing toruinteractive/ti-blog (0.13.1): Cloning e0d3296d01 from cache
  - Installing toruinteractive/ti-banner (0.13.1): Cloning cadf895998 from cache
  - Installing sentry/sentry (0.17.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing ramsey/uuid (3.7.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing mandrill/mandrill (1.0.55): Loading from cache
  - Installing fightbulc/moment (1.26.10): Loading from cache
  - Installing dompdf/dompdf (v0.7.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing toruinteractive/ti-cms (0.13.1): Cloning 6fd9d9fe53 from cache
  - Installing yiisoft/yii2-debug (dev-master b2cd366): Loading from cache
Generating autoload files
```

So my question is how can I make my own packages 'load' from cache to speed up my install process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is just the difference between git repos and prepared packages, that is cloning a git repo vs a dist(zip/tar) file.  Once cached the zip file just needs to be unzipped and you are done.

For a git repo, cloning is an operation that requires a bit more time, it is likely is going over the network to ensure the cached repo is still up to date, then doing the actual cached repo to working directory clone.

If you want your own packages to load from cache try distributing them in dist (zip/tar) format.